# Rackup Fails. Require Sinatra Fails

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rackup

I'm running `rackup config.ru`.

The config.ru file contains:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'

app = ->(env){

   status = 200
   headers = {"content-type" => "text/html"}
   body = ["<Html><Body><H1>Hello, World!</H1></Body></Html>"]

   [status, headers, body]

}

run app
```

Which returns:

```
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/konstantinosschoinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-base-1.0/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:1 - cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/konstantinosschoinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-base-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:6 - cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/konstantinosschoinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sinatra-base-1.0/lib/sinatra.rb:4 - cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/konstantinosschoinas/Desktop/projects/bookstore-api/config.ru:1 - cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/konstantinosschoinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rackup:23 - cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
```

Also my `gem env` output is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/konstantinosschoinas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
```

I installed Sinatra and Sinatra::Base with gem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the Sinatra gem to `sinatra-2.0.7`.

Run:

```
$ gem install sinatra -v 2.0.7
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you explain to me how you figured?

Comment: You're welcome) Just checked my sinatra version, because I encountered such a problem myself.